# FadeIn/FadeOut an addClass/removeClass JQuery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, addclass, removeclass

I am using the below JQuery code to add and remove a class that has a display:none property and add a class that has a display:block to three different divs positioned relatively. Basically I have a side navigation that has three links that, when clicked, I want to displays different divs on the page, one fading out and then the other fading in.

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#what-we-do, #location').hide();
        $('#who-we-are').show();    


        });

$(function() {
        $("#show-main-who").mousedown(function() {
            $('#what-we-do, #location').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $(this).addClass('hide-info');
            $(this).removeClass('show-info');

            });
        });
        $('#show-main-who').mouseup(function() {
            $('#who-we-are').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $(this).removeClass('hide-info');
                $(this).addClass('show-info');
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
        $("#show-main-what").mousedown(function() {
            $('#who-we-are, #location').fadeOut('fast',function() {
            $(this).addClass('hide-info');
            $(this).removeClass('show-info');


            });
        });
        $('#show-main-what').mouseup(function() {
            $('#what-we-do').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $(this).removeClass('hide-info');
                $(this).addClass('show-info');
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
        $("#show-main-location").mousedown(function() {
            $('#what-we-do, #who-we-are').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $(this).addClass('hide-info');
            $(this).removeClass('show-info');

            });
        });
        $('#show-main-location').mouseup(function() {
            $('#location').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $(this).removeClass('hide-info');
                $(this).addClass('show-info');
        });
    });
});
```

When you see my website at http://jacobbuller.com/testsites/peacock/ and use the side navigation you can see that the div does fade out but the other div fading in shows below it for an instant, then moves into place. It makes it look choppy and unprofessional, any idea how to fix this without having to make the divs positioned absolutely?

Comment: I don't know if this is your entire issue, but your second code snippet has an extra `});` at the end that doesn't belong.

Answer (score 1):

You have a period missing on the second line. Should read:-

```
$("#what-we-do, #location").fadeOut("slow", function() {
```

Comment: Thanks Yehuda, i'm an idiot. It still is a little choppy, the div keeps showing below the one its replacing then moving up. You can see it here http://jacobbuller.com/testsites/peacock/

Comment: create another class called show-info.  Assign this class to one of the pairs and hide-info to the other two, then when a link is pressed add remove show-info and add hide-info to the one being shown, and add show-info and remove hide-info from the new one to be shown.

Comment: I added a separate class called show-info with a display:block and I added into the JQuery code but I am still getting the same choppy look that I was having previously with the div showing below the other div before it fades out and then moving up to take its place. Also all the divs are being displayed when the page loads.

Comment: I was able to get it to show the first div and hide the others when the document loaded, still is choppy though...